# Some files are located outside of "MyApp" directory in my iOS app - why?

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm now developing my first iOS app, and I found that two of my classes (hence, four files) are located outside of my `MyApp/`.

So in my filesystem, here's the current situation:

```
My App
    - ClassA.h
    - ClassA.m
    - ClassB.h
    - ClassB.m
    MyApp/
    MyApp.xcodeproj/
    MyAppTests/
```

Other than the two classes, all of my class files are located in `MyApp` subdirectory. The other resources, such as Core Data model file or images are saved in the same directory.

However, why are the two classes, and only the two classes, located in the outside of `MyApp` subdirectory? When I move those files to the supposedly correct location, those files are no more "valid" in Xcode with the color of the file name is converted to red.

So here's my question:

- Why are those two files located there?
- Do they have any issues if they remain to be located there?
- Should I fix this issue and save it correctly? I think I haven't had any issues so far with the Simulator and the actual iPhone...

I use iOS 7 and Xcode 5.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**•Why are those two files located there?**
A: When you have created these files or imported from external directory, you may have not taken care of the group/folder these files are getting created/imported into. Hence they are inside the main app folder in the file system.

**•Do they have any issues if they remain to be located there?**
A: No, this is certainly not an issue in the correct functioning of your app, but it is always good to manage your files under groups/folders for better file structure and it is easier to find files when they become large in number.

**•Should I fix this issue and save it correctly? I think I haven't had any issues so far with the Simulator and the actual iPhone...**
A : This depends on you. If you like to keep your files in folders and like everythin arranged in some pattern, then yes you can divide the app into different folders. When you move the files in a folder, the reference of those in XCODE should change as well, and thats why you see those files in red in XCode. No worries. Just delete the files and add them again. Make sure you uncheck the option "Copy files under detsination group's folder".

Now, you may seem the option of creating New Groups inside XCode. But it is good to be aware that these groups do not create separate folders inside file system. These are just for Xcode refernce. So, a neat way is to create folders outside of XCode, and then import these folders(can be empty) in Xcode. Now when you add any file in these imported folders, even from XCode, it will go inside the correct folder in file system.

I am sorry I am not on my MAC right now, so cannot paste actual images, showing how to do it. Feel  free to comment, if I have instead of solving the issue, have rather confused you more:D

Comment: Thanks for the great clarification! I removed references to those files, moved them to the subdirectory from within Terminal, and then added those moved files to Xcode again, and my app got working properly.

Answer (score 0):

You can put your source files wherever you want, as long as Xcode knows where to find them. You can leave them here, or organize it in another way, as you seem to be willing to do.

So, if you want to move these files in your `Myapp/` subfolder, just move them there, and when Xcode complains it can't find them, highlight all those files in red in the navigator, and in the "File inspector" pane (right hand side of the window), click on the little Folder icon to browse to the new location. If you selected all files you don't need to do that 4 times, Xcode will find it out by itself.